# django ckeditor image upload

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm using Django-ckeditor in my website.

I'm especially using

**RichTextUploadingField()**

in my model. and other option just works fine, except image upload.

### 1. Error Message

I'm getting an error message of

"Incorrect Server Response" and especially, chrome devtools indicates that

---

ckeditor.js:21 [CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error.

ckeditor.js:21 [CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_errors-section-filetools-response-error

---

### 2. Guess

I have tried uploading images using ckeditor in my admin page,

authorized as superuser in django, it works.

However, logged in as the normal user account, I've tried the same thing, but it does not work.

So my guess is it has some kind of authorization problem. But I can't figure out where to start debugging in my django-ckeditor.

What things should I be checking? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are saying that you can't upload the image via the admin panel with staff permissions or via a form in the frontend?

Comment: via admin panel, with staff permission(superuser), I can upload the image. However, in frontend form, I can't.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the default urls are decorated with @staff_member_required(https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/master/ckeditor_uploader/urls.py). To avoid this, instead of including the urls like so `url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))` you could define them one by one in your urls.py with the login_required decorator:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from ckeditor_uploader import views

urlpatterns = [
     .....your other urls
    url(r'^ckeditor/upload/', login_required(views.upload), name='ckeditor_upload'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/browse/', never_cache(login_required(views.browse)), name='ckeditor_browse'),
]
```

Like this you are limiting the uploads to all users that are logged in.

Comment: I've added those to my url, but it's not working... :( Especially, in local environment, it works fine. However in web-hosting env, I use pythonanywhere, it does not work. Are there any specific things to consider more? I really appreciate your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @dongminkim What do you mean by dosent work? You can't access the url or something else?

Comment: I've accessed to the url file and fixed the code as you mentioned. In local env, all works fine. However, when I deploy(to pythonanywhere), it doesn't work( it gives me an alert message of "incorrect server response").

Comment: How do you get this error? When you access the url or when you try to upload something?

Comment: This answer is very helpful. But with the current version of django, you have to import login_required this way: from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required. Also import from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache and remember to remove path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')) that you got from the CKEditor documentation before the image upload will work for all users.

Answer (score 2):

Add following imports in the project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from ckeditor_uploader import views as ckeditor_views
```

Replace the following row in the urls.py:

```
path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

with

```
path('ckeditor/upload/', login_required(ckeditor_views.upload), name='ckeditor_upload'),
path('ckeditor/browse/', never_cache(login_required(ckeditor_views.browse)), name='ckeditor_browse'),
```

Answer (score 0):

it works if you are logged in as an admin(localhost:8000/admin), simple is that.